# Open a specific InfoWindow without click nor in upload or initialization in Google Maps V3 Places

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api

I would like to open a specific `InfoWindow` among the 20 you get from Google Places.

First I need to determine which one to open. So, once I know the one to open, I would like to open it by Google Places Business ID -> `place.id`.

So, far I've tested it by marker order ( i ) like this:

```
openInfoWindowBy(i){
    infowindow.open(map,i);
}
```

I just called: `openInfoWindowBy(1);` and `InfoWindow` 1, didn't open. The click event works fine:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', getDetails(placesArr[i], i));
markers[i].setMap(map);
addplace(placesArr[i], i);
```

What am I doing wrong? And will it be possible to open it by `place.id`?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [sample](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-search) in this section of the Google Maps [developer's guide](http://goo.gl/CCb10). The Places library in V3 of the Google Maps API returns the results in an array, so as you loop through the array, you should use the index value, not the place.id to loop/add/rererence the markers.

That said, your existing code for `openInfoWindowBy` references the index, rather than the index within the `markers` array.  It seems that it should be this:

```
openInfoWindowBy(i){
   infowindow.open(map,markers[i]);
}
```

You need to make the second argument `markers[1]`

Comment: Thanks Andres, I have tried this: 

function openInfoWindowBy(i){
    infowindow.open(map,markers[i]);
}
setTimeout('openInfoWindowBy(2)',3000);

And no success, any ideas why?

Comment: Why is `openInfoWindowBy(2)` in quotes?  You're calling a function, not executable code (like say `alert()`), so you don't need to enclose the argument in quotes.  Also, is 2 a valid index?